# sorting json items via object values

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

If I have the below JSON and I need to loop through each object in the array and sort them via the num key and spit out the name value, how do I do that again? I'm having a real brain fart and can't remember.

```
  [{
    "name": "bob",
    "num": 16
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "num": 45
  },

  {
    "name": "tyler",
    "num": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "rebecca",
    "num": 70
  },
  {
    "name": "michelle",
    "num": 81
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks y'all. End of the day sort of thing when you're forgetting everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to sort ascending, you can use the builtin function `sort` with custom comparator, then `map` the results to a name array:

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "bob",
    "num": 16
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "num": 45
  },

  {
    "name": "tyler",
    "num": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "rebecca",
    "num": 70
  },
  {
    "name": "michelle",
    "num": 81
  }
];

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => a.num - b.num).map(e => e.name));
```

Use `b.num - a.num` for a descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
lst = []; //your list
function sortnum(a, b) {
    return a.num - b.num;
}
var result = lst.sort(sortnum).map(function (item) { return item.name; });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requests this task can be performed with something like this :

```
[{
    "name": "bob",
    "num": 16
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "num": 45
  },

  {
    "name": "tyler",
    "num": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "rebecca",
    "num": 70
  },
  {
    "name": "michelle",
    "num": 81
  }].sort((a,b)=>a.num-b.num).map(a=>a.name)
```